# I have problem what to use

Tags: spoken-english, indian-english

Is this correct " We would also love to notify you "

Or this is correct " We would also loves to notify you "

Help will really appreciated

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before they post a question, maybe quoting what they have found, and then explain what they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Modal auxiliary verbs such as "can, could, may, must, shall, should and would" take the infinitive form of the lexical (main) verb - in this case to "love".

This applies whether the subject is singular (He,she) or plural (We).

Thus it's correct to say: "We would also love to notify you".

The rule changes if a second auxiliary verb is inserted into the sentence when the past participle form may be used:

eg: "We would also HAVE loved to notify you".

http://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-after-modals

https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/modal-auxiliary-verbs/